# What happens if a new row is inserted when the primary key exists when using auto increment?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, auto-increment, bigint

I am using PGsql and transferred some data from another database into my new one. The table has records starting at PK 200. The tables primary key (bigint - autoincrementing) is currently starting at 0. If I continue to insert records, eventually it will reach 200. My question is, will these records create an issue when trying to insert record 200? or will PGsql know the conflict, then find the next available AI index (say 234)?
Thanks! If it will cause a conflict, how can I set the current index of my table to the last index of data? (like 234).

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, will these records create an issue when trying to insert record 200?

Assuming that you have a `serial` column or the-like: yes, this will create an issue. The serial has no knowledge that some sequences are not available, sp this will result in a duplicate key error. Meanwhile the sequence increments also on such errors, and the next call will return the next number, and so on.

This is easily reproducible:

```
create table t (id serial primary key, val text);

insert into t (id, val) values (2, 'blocker');
-- 1 rows affected

insert into t (val) values ('foo');
-- 1 rows affected

insert into t (val) values ('bar');
-- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_pkey"
-- DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.

insert into t (val) values ('baz');
-- 1 rows affected

select * from t order by id;

id | val    
-: | :------
 1 | foo    
 2 | blocker
 3 | baz
```

One solution is to reset the sequence: the only safe starting point is the high watermark of the table:

```
select setval(
    't_id_seq', 
    coalesce((select max(id) + 1 from t), 1), 
    false
);
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=af28e513a3b7f270a8a88d33be35fe62)**: you can uncomment the `setval()` statement to see how it avoids the error.

Comment: Not sure what this means, but the default value is this: nextval('line_inventory_logsheet_head_logsheet_id_seq'::regclass)